# Raster Grid Editor in QGIS

Tags: qgis, raster, qgis-3, qgis-plugins, geotiff-tiff

I currently use QGIS to view, post-process, and conduct other mapping tasks that utilize a number of GeoTIFFs, some of which may be quite large in their overall dimensions/size. Consider the following GeoTIFF inside of QGIS, which has dimensions of ~2,500i & 1,500j:

[image: GeoTIFF in QGIS]

I am looking to make modifications to values of this GeoTIFF at specific locations on this grid, which could vary from additions/subtractions (+/- 2), percentage increases/decreases (+/- 5%), etc. I have previously downloaded & tested Serval, which does work but requires the user to enter which value is desired and works by selecting individual grid cells. This introduces prolonged workflow when rasters with larger dimensions are selected. My intention is to make the aforementioned adjustments with the option to do so over a wider spatial range (say 3i x 3j, 6i x 6j, and 12i x 12j) per click.

Does a QGIS plugin currently exist that allows users more functionality to apply the adjustments as described above? If not, is a company or individual interested in constructing this functionality into a plugin in exchange for payment?